# SQL table function or means to tell if identity column has been used?

Tags: sql, identity-column

I was curious if there is a way to tell if an IDENTITY column has ever been incremented if there is no data within the table. (i.e. data item was inserted, then deleted)

Comment: This is a platform-specific question since you are trying to obtain metadata. What database are you using?

Comment: E.g., for Oracle, there is no identity specific to one table, it uses sequences that may be shared among tables.

Comment: This question is for SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use [this approach](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/23/sql-server-query-to-find-seed-values-increment-values-and-current-identity-column-value-of-the-table/):

```
SELECT IDENT_SEED(TABLE_NAME) AS Seed,
    IDENT_INCR(TABLE_NAME) AS Increment,
    IDENT_CURRENT(TABLE_NAME) AS Current_Identity,
    TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1
    AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Note that you can reset the seed value in SQL Server, so the above apporach only tells you the current state of the seed, not whether there was ever any data in the table or not.

Comment: The reason I am asking is because I was messing around with my test tables and truncated all of the tables even if they have never been used before. What I noticed was that the tables that have never been used before, when data is inserted the IDENTITY stays at ZERO (0) just for that one record and then it increments to ONE (1) after. Have you seen this behavior before? I am truncating because I have relationships associated with the tables

Comment: This is a common SQL Server issue. You can run `DBCC CHECKIDENT('MyTable', RESEED, 0)` after you truncate to make the identity starts at 1.

Comment: That is the thing I cannot truncate as msot of these tables with this is has a foreign relationship